# Django does not migrate app

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working on a django project for learning purpose. I've created an app `organization` and installed it. When I run `python manage.py makemigrations organization` it works fine shows the changes.

```
Migrations for 'organization':
  organization/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Organization
    - Create model Principle
```

But when I run `python manage.py migrate organization` it doesn't migrate and shows no changes to apply.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: organization
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I'm using `postgresql` and tried `drop owned by user_name;` after deleting all `migrations` folders. But still doesn't work. It shows every time the same thing. How to resolve this ?

Environment: 
OS version Ubuntu 16.04 
Django version 1.10.3 
PostgreSQL version 9.5.7

**organization/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField    

class Principle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    status = models.BooleanField()


class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    liceneses = [
        ('pvt','Private Limited',),
        ('pub','Public Limited',),
        ('part','Partnership',),
        ('prop','proprietary',)
    ]

    licenese_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=liceneses)
    key_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    key_person_position = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    key_person_contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    primary_organization_contact = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    organization_address = models.TextField()
    additional_info = JSONField()
    date_of_registration = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Try `python manage.py migrate` without the appname. And look at the output of `python manage.py showmigrations` to see if the migration is already applied

Comment: @fechnert I have already tried that, same result. `No migrations to apply`.

Comment: @fechnert `showmigrations` doesn't show `organization` but shows other app `account`, `admin`, `auth`, `avatar` etc.

Comment: In pgAdmin or in command line, display entries for table 'django_migrations'. It will show you the current migration state. For example, if you previously applied a migration 0001_initial for app 'organization', then deleted the migrations folder, then re-created the migration file, it cannot being applied.

Comment: Also, make sure you added your app 'organization' to installed_apps in settings.py

Comment: @Antwane `organization` is added to `installed_apps`.

Comment: @Antwane After deleting `migrations` folder if I delete all tables in the database too and then try migrating can it be applied ? or still it can't be applied ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in these case delete all the migrations files from migration folder except `__init__.py` file for all apps, make sure you have the apps in the installed apps

then delete the database tables

NOTE: Be **careful** to backup important FILES when you delete your DATABASE !

```
run python manage.py migrate
run python manage.py makemigrations
run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: How to delete all tables ?? Is it ok running `drop owned by user_name;` to delete all tables ?

Comment: you can even drop the database using drop database as you dont need the values i guess, so drop the database and create a fresh database